# sphinx search, how match wordform token twice

Tags: sphinx

Imagine we have 4 products:

"iPhone 3g, iPhone 3gs, iPhone 4, iPhone 4s"

and use wordforms for it:

```
iPhone 3g > ip3
iPhone 3gs > ip3s
iPhone 4 > ip4
iPhone 4s > ip4s
```

This need for matching only iPhone 3g, not 3gs when search "iPhone 3g"

Problem is: If user search "iPhone" I should found all 4 versions.
But! "iPhone" in seource text will be replaced by CRC32 through wordforms sphinx mechanism
How I can solve this problem and found all 4 phoducts when search "iPhone" or found only one product if search him?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that `wordforms` (nor `exceptions` for that matter) will help with this.

But I beleive you could use `regexp_filter`

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-regexp-filter

Something like

```
regexp_filter = iphone\ (\d\w*)\b => iphone ip\1
```

This does effectively the same tranform as the above wordforms, but also includes iphone as a single word, so it could be matched on its own.

(the only slight wrinkle I can see, is not sure how to make the regular express replacement non case-sensitive - so will either have to include all the possible spellings if phone in the search string, or have multiple filters for each combination)

Comment: Actuylly, just figured out how to do case insensitive replacements, see http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=11453